# Missing vertical lines in tabu

Tags: tables, tabu, line

I'm trying to make a nice looking tabu, as part of a hand-in I'm working on. And if I simply use `l`,`c` or `r` as arguments for the columns, it looks good.

However, the problem arises when I try to define a width for the colums (`p{3.75cm}` in this case). The vertical lines meant to separate the lower part of the tabu into three parts, disappears.

[image]

This is how I'd like the tabu to look, only with pre-defined width for the columns like so:

[image]

Hower as you can see, the sepearion lines in this case are gone. How can I get them back?

```
\documentclass[danish]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=14pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{babel}

% Define colors
\definecolor{UMLetBlue}{RGB}{130,130,255}
\definecolor{UMLetGray}{RGB}{189,189,189}
\definecolor{UMLetGreen}{RGB}{130,255,130}
\definecolor{UMLetRed}{RGB}{255,130,130}
\definecolor{UMLetYellow}{RGB}{255,255,130}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \taburowcolors 2 {white .. UMLetGray}
    \begin{tabu}{p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}l}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Scenarie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Resultat}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Godkendt}} &  \\
        \hline
        A   &   B   &   C   &   \\
        D   &   E   &   F   &   \\
        G   &   H   &   I   &
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \taburowcolors 2 {white .. UMLetGray}
    \begin{tabu}{l|l|ll}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Scenarie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Resultat}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Godkendt}} &  \\
        \hline
        A                                       & B                                      & C                                      &  \\
        C                                       & D                                      & E                                      &  \\
        F                                       & G                                      & H                                      & 
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{My caption2}
    \label{my-label2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you meant vertical lines to be there from top row to bottom row? @Julnaz

Comment: Yes, like shown in [tabel 1]. I would like the row underneath the first one to be divided into 3, with a clear line between them.

Comment: vertical line are on both images. you have pdf viewer issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[danish]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=14pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{babel}

% Define colors
\definecolor{UMLetBlue}{RGB}{130,130,255}
\definecolor{UMLetGray}{RGB}{189,189,189}
\definecolor{UMLetGreen}{RGB}{130,255,130}
\definecolor{UMLetRed}{RGB}{255,130,130}
\definecolor{UMLetYellow}{RGB}{255,255,130}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \taburowcolors 2 {white .. UMLetGray}
    \begin{tabu}{p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}l}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Scenarie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Resultat}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Godkendt}} &  \\
        \hline
        A   &   B   &   C   &   \\
        D   &   E   &   F   &   \\
        G   &   H   &   I   &
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \taburowcolors 2 {white .. UMLetGray}
    \begin{tabu}{l|l|ll}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Scenarie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Resultat}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Godkendt}} &  \\
        \hline
        A                                       & B                                      & C                                      &  \\
        C                                       & D                                      & E                                      &  \\
        F                                       & G                                      & H                                      & 
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{My caption2}
    \label{my-label2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

New modified code

```
\documentclass[danish]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=14pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{babel}

% Define colors
\definecolor{UMLetBlue}{RGB}{130,130,255}
\definecolor{UMLetGray}{RGB}{189,189,189}
\definecolor{UMLetGreen}{RGB}{130,255,130}
\definecolor{UMLetRed}{RGB}{255,130,130}
\definecolor{UMLetYellow}{RGB}{255,255,130}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \taburowcolors 2 {white .. UMLetGray}
    \begin{tabu}{p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}l}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Scenarie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Resultat}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Godkendt}} &  \\
        \hline
        A   &   B   &   C   &   \\
        D   &   E   &   F   &   \\
        G   &   H   &   I   &
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \taburowcolors 2 {white .. UMLetGray}
    \begin{tabu}{l|l|ll}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Scenarie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Resultat}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Godkendt}} &  \\
        \hline
        A                                       & B                                      & C                                      &  \\
        C                                       & D                                      & E                                      &  \\
        F                                       & G                                      & H                                      & 
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{My caption2}
    \label{my-label2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. While this does indeed give me back the seperation lines in the lower tabel, I was hoping for a solution that would still leave them out of the top part `Scenarie Resultat Godkendt` Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The vertical rules won't disappear, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass[danish]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=14pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{babel}

% Define colors
\definecolor{UMLetBlue}{RGB}{130,130,255}
\definecolor{UMLetGray}{RGB}{189,189,189}
\definecolor{UMLetGreen}{RGB}{130,255,130}
\definecolor{UMLetRed}{RGB}{255,130,130}
\definecolor{UMLetYellow}{RGB}{255,255,130}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}|p{3.75cm}}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{white}{UMLetGray}
\Body
  \RowStyle{\bfseries\centering}\Block{1-*}{}
  Scenarie & Resultat & Godkendt \\
  \hline
  A & B & C \\
  C & D & E \\
  F & G & H 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{My caption2}
\label{my-label2}
\end{table}



\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{l|l|l}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{white}{UMLetGray}
\Body
  \RowStyle{\bfseries}\Block{1-*}{}
  Scenarie & Resultat & Godkendt \\
  \hline
  A & B & C \\
  C & D & E \\
  F & G & H 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{My caption2}
\label{my-label2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]